# Converting eval code into ordinary php code

Tags: php

Is it possible to have just normal php code and not use `eval()` function in such case?

My eval code is following:

```
eval('$'.$var.'["'.$key.'"]="'.$value.'";');
```

And what I am doing is following:

```
function config_update($array, $var="result")
{ 
    global $result, $dbi;

    while (list($key,$value)=each($array))
    {
        if (is_array($value))
        { 
            config_update($value, $var.'["'.$key.'"]'); 
        } 
        else
        { 
            for ($i=0; $i<count($value);$i++)
            {
                if ($value == "{FROM_DB}")
                {
                    $query = $dbi->prepare("SELECT `value` FROM `".PRE."config` WHERE `key`=?;")->execute($key)->results();

                    if (!$query) 
                    {
                        trigger_error("There is no such key as `{$key}` in config database",E_USER_ERROR);
                        exit;
                    }
                    else
                        $value = str_replace("{FROM_DB}",$query[0]['value'],$value);
                }
                eval('$'.$var.'["'.$key.'"]="'.$value.'";');
                //$$var[$key] = $value; #smth like that..
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I basically need to update variable values with {FROM_DB} with values coming from DB.

Comment: "$$var[$key] = $value;" should work... isn't it?

Comment: `Warning: Illegal string offset 'doc_root' in H:\xampp\htdocs\app_portable\boot.php on line 80` and not only `doc_root` such message loops for different configuration key names...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the php manual on variable variables you should use {} when working with array based variable variables to avoid unknown behavior.

```
${$var}[$key] = $value
```

see [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: no problem, anything to reduce the use of eval out in the wild.

Comment: This is *still ugly* as it still uses "variable variables". I would recommend switching to the proper root ADT. (Very few languages support "variable variables"; and yet almost all computer languages support this same goal/operation.)

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use:

```
$$var = array();
$$var[$key] = $value;
```

It would evaluate as:

```
$result[$key] = $value;
```

Assuming that `$var = 'result'`.

Comment: I know, but it does not work in my case for unknown reason and that is what I try to ask

Comment: Have you defined it as an array beforehand?